# Phalcon: How i can design a website with multi languages?

Tags: phalcon, multilingual

Later i worked with **symfony** framework. In this framework we can easily build a multi language project by using **FOSUserBundle**. But i do'nt know what to do in **phalcon**! In the Phalcon documentation ([multi-lingual-support](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/translate.html#multi-lingual-support)) explained a way for it! But if i have many languages this way is too difficult!

Do yo know about any **provided library** for **multi language projects**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the [Phalcon\Translate](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Translate.html) to translate all your strings in respective arrays - one file per language. The reference in the documentation as you correctly posted is [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/translate.html#multi-lingual-support) and it refers to the native array adapter.

There are additional adapters in the [incubator](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Translate/Adapter) repo, for PO files or database driven.

You might also want to see the [internationalization](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/intl.html) area in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your answer! My website needs to translate about all languages in the world! In your opinion what is the best way for my site? Can you guide me?

Comment: I would go with the database adapter and a table to hold the translated strings. You will also need a languages table. You can a language that will be your master. If a user wants a different language and the X string is not there then your app should revert to the master language. An interface can be built to add/translate different strings.

Comment: this way is so nice! but my website should translate any text! even if this text has been sent from a user as a comment! In your way we can translate some special words which saved in my database, while my texts my be different from that saved in my website database!

Comment: In that case I would suggest hooking up with the Google Translate API so that you can let your users translate text on demand.

Comment: PHP Alternative website is a good example: http://blog.phalconphp.com/post/24622423072/sample-application-php-alternative-site

Comment: Thanks my friend... I had seen and download it later! but it is unsuitable for my purpose!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this piece of code
https://bitbucket.org/moderndeveloperllc/phalconlocale/src

Comment: Please add more details to answer, like some example and additionally link to external solutions.